# Irreducibility of the Jacobians of a curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, representable-functor, picard-scheme

I'm studying Jacobian varieties.I assume that the existence of the Jacobian variety for  a curve and attempt to show irreducibility of the Jacobian for a curve according to Remark:IV.4.10.9 of Hartshorne's book.

Let $C$ be a complete smooth curve of genus $g$ over an algebraic field $k$, let $P_0 \in C$ and let $J(C)$ is the Jacobian of C. By the universal property of the Jacobian, we can  obtain the morphism $\varphi : C^g \rightarrow J(C)$ such that $\varphi(k): C(k) \ni(P_1 ,\dots,P_n) \mapsto \mathcal{O}_C(P_0+\dots+P_n-nP_0)\in J(C)(k)=\mathrm{Pic}^\circ(C)$. Then there exists an open subset $U$ of $J(C)$ such that the fibers of $\varphi$ at any point of U are finite sets. My book conclude that this means $J(C)$ is irreducible. But I cannot understand this. Could someone please tell me this reason?

Comment: Searching for "jacobian hyperelliptic curve" shows many texts about the construction of the abelian group $Pic^0(C)$ and its algebraized variety

Comment: I'm also confused in this remark. However my problem is about the definition of this $\varphi(k)$. It gives a map from the closed points of $C(k)$ into the closed points of $J$. But I don't understand why this map defines a morphism. If it's the case, the irreducibility can be proved just by its own definition, and the fact that the closed points are dense.